# Writing sql query for getting search result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

When i am writing sql query for getting the search result through the text box it is repeating the same result for several time. I need the result only once. Please help me to solve this issue
This is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM pm_record, dead_body
WHERE pm_record.sr_no = dead_body.sr_no
AND dead_body.sr_no = '$input_search'
OR pm_record.date_of_autopsy = '$input_search'
OR pm_record.status = '$input_search'
OR dead_body.sex = '$input_search'
OR dead_body.f_name = '$input_search'
OR dead_body.date_of_death = '$input_search'
OR pm_record.staff_id = '$input_search'
OR pm_record.assiated = '$input_search'
OR pm_record.inq_no_ISD = '$input_search'
OR pm_record.circumstances = '$input_search'
```

Comment: This query is probably not doing what you think it does. Check if you need parenthesis around AND or ORs

Comment: No it is giving me the same repeating result even i put parenthesis

Comment: show you table structures and records

Comment: If you can please create an sqlfiddle with your database table structure and some sample data that would be most helpful for everyone to help you figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

use `SELECT DISTINCT *` instead of `SELECT *`

Comment: It is not  working. It is giving me the same repeating results

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` for that. Specify only the columns you need instead of *.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM pm_record, dead_body
WHERE pm_record.sr_no = dead_body.sr_no
    AND dead_body.sr_no = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.date_of_autopsy = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.status = '$input_search'
    OR dead_body.sex = '$input_search'
    OR dead_body.f_name = '$input_search'
    OR dead_body.date_of_death = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.staff_id = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.assiated = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.inq_no_ISD = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.circumstances = '$input_search'
```

Comment: As I mentioned only specify columns you need instead of * in the SELECT. For e.g. SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2 ......

Comment: I need all the fields from my table. Now i changed my coding as you said bt it is repeating. For example ihave only 2 records in female. But these 2 results are repeating me for 9 times. So i get 18 results

Comment: Are the rows really distinct in the table? Give me examples.

Comment: yeah rows are distinct. But only result is repeating.

Comment: For example i have only 2 records in female. If i search for female records in my table it shouls show me 2 records. But these 2 results are repeating me for 9 times. So i get 18 results . The results are repeating.

Comment: and your problem is really in SQL query? I think so your problem may be in your application loop... this query can not return repeated rows, BUT i see you run query for 2 tables. You should run query for one and second table and compare results.

Comment: When you run the query against the DB what do you get?

Comment: I get the same repeating result when i run the query aginst the DB

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM pm_record, dead_body
    WHERE pm_record.sr_no = dead_body.sr_no
    AND 
    (dead_body.sr_no = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.date_of_autopsy = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.status = '$input_search'
    OR dead_body.sex = '$input_search'
    OR dead_body.f_name = '$input_search'
    OR dead_body.date_of_death = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.staff_id = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.assiated = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.inq_no_ISD = '$input_search'
    OR pm_record.circumstances = '$input_search' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` keyword to remove duplicate records and also use `IN` clause to remove multiple `OR` operators to improve query performance.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM pm_record p INNER JOIN dead_body d ON p.sr_no = d.sr_no
WHERE '$input_search' IN (d.sr_no, p.date_of_autopsy, p.status, d.sex, d.f_name, 
                          d.date_of_death, p.staff_id, p.assiated, p.inq_no_ISD, 
                          p.circumstances);
```